# How to check if a list contains a boolean value

Tags: python, list

This is a part of my code:

```
for d in errors[:]:
    if False in d:
        Ic.append(current_mA2)
```

And this is in `errors`:

```
[True, True, True, False, True, True, False, True,True,True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,False]
```

I just want to know if the value False is in the list.

Comment: If you're using `False in d` to check if `False` is in `d`, then apply that same principle...

Comment: You should be using `if False in errors`, not `if False in d`, so you don't need that `for` loop.

Comment: As a bit offtopic: if a variable is called `errors` I expect `True` values to mean that an error happened and `False` values the absense of an error. Is this your behaviour? Your question made me think that it is the opposite one and then either the name of the `list` or the values should be swapped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just:

```
if False in errors:
    Ic.append(current_mA2)
```

to directly check if `False` is in list. `list` implements the `__contains__` magic method so you can just do that.

Comment: This works for the specific case the OP presents. Be warned, though, if the list `errors` contains an integer 0 etc, it automatically returns true, eg., `False in [0, True]` returns `True`.

Comment: That's because `0 == False` is `True` in python. `all([0, True])` is also `False`.`sum([True, True, True])` is btw 3. If you have heterogeneous lists and must check for the presence of `False` you have to use `is`.

Answer (score 23):

No one suggested using `all()` (python doc [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)).
All checks wether **all values in a list interpret to True**, meaning, if at least one of them is False, it will return False:

```
> a_list = [True, True, False]
> b_list = [True, True, True]
> all(a_list)
False
> all(b_list)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
isFalseIn = False in errors
```

I think that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
any(lambda x: x == False, errors)
```

`any` checks if there is any element in collection that matches predicate.

As pointed by others, in your case you can just use:

```
if False in errors:
```

Comment: That's horribly inefficient considering alternate options.

Comment: `x = True` will raise errors... It should be `== True`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yup, right, too much functional programming.

Comment: You should actually check for `False` as that is what OP asked

Comment: @zondo Why is it horribly inefficient? Any stops when it finds a match.

Comment: @Adirio OP changed his question.

Comment: @mateuszlewko: It creates a lambda function and then calls it for each value until there is a match. Using `in` as I mentioned in a comment is much better.

Comment: @zondo What about the default `any` and `all`behaviour without passing a `lambda`?

Comment: @Adirio: That wouldn't be as bad, but even ignoring the efficiency, using `in` is a much cleaner and more intuitive approach.

Comment: @zondo well `not all(errors)` also looks nice for me, but i was asking about efficiency right now, just as an offtopic fact

Comment: @Adirio: I ran `dis.dis()` on the `in` method and the `not all(errors)`. Using `all()` requires one more instruction. The only instruction that is the same, actually, is `LOAD_NAME` for `errors`. Using `all()`, it loads the function from the name, calls it, applies `not` and takes the return value. Using `in`, it loads the `False` constant, uses the COMPARE_OP `in`, and takes the return value. That seems to ignore what goes on inside the `all()` function, and still `in` comes out ahead.

Comment: In addition to the inefficiency of using a `lambda` function, it would be better to return `not x` than `x == False`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
errors= str(errors)
for d in errors[:]:
if 'False' in d:
    Ic.append(current_mA2)
```

It converts the list's boolean values to strings so to alter them. If the string 'false' is in errors, do whatever.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could use a flag variable like

```
flag = false
```

Then you can do the loop to the array and compare each one with the flag.